# express 3.0 and passport authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I'm using express@3.0.0beta4 with passport@0.1.12 and using local srategy for authentication.

Everything seems to work fine and it redirects on success and failure correctly

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); // true
  res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.id );
});
```

But if I add ensureAuthenticated on profile route

```
app.get('/users/:id', ensureAuthenticated, routes.user);

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); // false
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

it redirects me back to '/' (which is login page) instead of '/users/id' (user profile) after login. The problem is req.isAuthenticated() always return false and there is no req.user variable in debug.

Is it problem with express 3 and passport interaction or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem too, but turns out it was because I was using express sessions without specifying a data store for session data.  That meant session data was being stored in RAM, and since I was using multiple workers, the session storage wasn't shared between workers.  I reconfigured my express session to use a `RedisStore` instead, and `isAuthenticated()` started returning true as expected.

```
app.use express.session
    secret: '...'
    store: new RedisStore
      host: redisUrl.hostname
      port: redisUrl.port
      db: ...
      pass: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

authenticate() is middleware. from the docs:

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Comment: It is the sipmlest way to use it and it changes nothing. Still if I add ensureAuthenticated on '/' rout (redirectin to '/login' if req.isAuthenticated() is false) I've got wrong routing because of req.isAuthenticated() is always false.

Comment: Oh, no! Actualy it is true now, but still I've got wrong redirection in
app.get('/profile', ensureAuthenticated, routes.profile);

Comment: Yeah, don't put the ensureAuthenticated in the /login path. And in your ensureAuthenticated function redirect to /login.

Comment: I've change the code and highlight the problem. So I need /users/id not to be avalible without auth, so I protect the path /users/id with ensureAuthentication middleware, and the result is - I can't login to the profile /users/id

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I test it with `curl -L -d "name=Test&password=1"` and [`curl -L`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/curl/) do not work as I expected. But it works just fine with web-browser.

Comment: If your post data was really `name:Test&password:1` then it's no wonder it did not work. It has to be `name=Test&password=1`.

Comment: Sure, it was valid request. I just misstyped it here.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with this issue for ages. What fixed it for me was changing the `maxAge` property of the session cookie - it was too low before:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser()); 
app.use(express.session({
  secret: config.session.secret,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1800000, //previously set to just 1800 - which was too low
    httpOnly: true
  }
}));
```

After this change, `req.isAuthenticated()` returned true