# User is not authenticated after res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having an issue where despite logging in successfully (as evidenced by the successRedirect handler triggering), the request is still not authenticated, so my authentication middleware sends us back to the login page again.

My routes look as follows:

```
// ROUTES

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('imconfusedindex.html'); // this never gets sent.
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldap-auth', {
    successRedirect: '/home',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

}

// route middleware to make sure a user is logged in
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

  // if user is authenticated, we'll all float on OK
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  // otherwise, redirect them to the login page
  res.redirect('/login');
}
```

And my passport configuration looks like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  connection.query("select * from users where user_id = " + id, function(err, rows) {
    done(err, rows[0]);
  });
});

passport.use('ldap-auth', new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    done(null, {user_id: 2, username: 'bob'});
  })
);
```

As you can see in the passport configuration, I'm returning a dummy user every time.  Doing more debugging shows that the request is being authenticated, but after the redirect, it is no longer authenticated.

Unsure what to do, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh I'm really stupid...the answer lurked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473507/express-3-0-and-passport-authentication) but when I read it I didn't quite put 2 and 2 together.

I'm lacking an `express-session` (didn't even include my server config here so even harder to debug).  As soon as I set up an session, it worked.

In case someone else has this same issue, make sure that in your app config, you include something like:

```
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'dontderplikeme'});
```

When you add in passport and include `app.use(passport.session())`, this is the session that it will be using to store credentials into.